# How to change application language runtime without restarting application in ios with objective c?

Tags: objective-c

currently I am using the code below to change the application language.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"French", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

but it works on restarting application.

I want to change application language on selecting from drop down without restarting application.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this [library](https://github.com/Baglan/MCLocalization) to change the language, on the go!

Answer (score 0):

> set your language text using NSLocalizedString(<#key#>, <#comment#>)
>   and push again same viewController